# SSH on linux | CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, port

I have a Linux server using CentOS.
I have changed the SSH config to make it a little more secure,
First I changed the from from default 21 (or 22?) to 34786. This way if someone tries to hack in at least they have to guess the port?

But my question is, I have heard there are tools out there which can find out which port my SSH config has been set to? making this security measure useless? Is this true or not.

Regards

Comment: This is security by obscurity, which is at most an addition to real security measures. So don't count soley on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if someone wants to hack your specific server, they can just do a port scan and find the port anyway. This doesn't make this useless, because most attacks on SSH are not targeted, they just try to connect to port 22 on all systems they can reach, usually with large botnets. In my experience, switching SSH ports reduced the daily attempts from thousands to exactly zero.

The more important security measure is to disable root access and password based authentication for SSH and use key-based auth exclusively. There are plenty of guides how to do this both on ServerFault and the general internet.

Edit:

Add/edit the following into your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Make sure key based login works before the next step:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: yes, i have also declined root access to :) but havnt heard of disabling password based authentication for SSH. any guidance towards this will be appreciated

Comment: @user234360 this is quite common and well documented. It's customary to try to help yourself before asking others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning all 3700 million routable IPv4 addresses for SSH severs on port 22 is doable. Researchers have even published analysis of the security of host keys obtained through this method.

Scanning all 65535 port numbers on each of 3700 million routable IPv4 addresses is not likely to be feasible. And this is why moving to a non-standard port number will protect you against untargeted attacks.

Against a targeted attack, it will however do no good. If the attacker is targeting just one IP address, scanning all 65535 port numbers can be done in a short time. To protect against a targeted attack I have two recommendations:

Configure the server to only accept key based authentication as described by @SvW. If you run a ssh command with `ssh -v hostname`, you should see something like this:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
```

Make sure to install security updates every time they become available.

Answer (score 0):

yes. they can do a port scan to find out, it may they take awhile, the best thing you can do is install Config firewall configure it to block SSH Attacks from bots. the next best thing to do is disable the user to connect via SSH